# iPhone SDK 3.0: where is the Bluetooth?

Tags: iphone, sdk, bluetooth

i'm participating in the iPhone Developer Program and i have access to the iPhone 3.0 firmware and SDK.

one of the new features of the iPhone 3.0 -- is ability to use Bluetooth, but i can't find any documentation about it. 
can someone point me please -- where is it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The only way of using bluetooth directly is if you join the Made for iPod / Works With iPhone program and integrate the Apple authentication chip into your custom device. Once you've done that, you can use the ExternalAccessory framework which exposes a low-level IO stream API to the device.

Frameworks like Core Audio will let you play and record music via bluetooth headsets and the Gamekit framework will let you discover and talk to other devices via bluetooth, but the fact that it's bluetooth is not exposed to the developer at all.

Comment: Do you have any link where one can read more about the demands for a custom device (a chip, weird?).

Comment: You'll need to join the Made for iPod / Works With iPhone program and sign the appropriate NDAs before getting access to that information.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the GameKit API - it provides simple high level access to BlueTooth connections between devices (built on Apple's Bonjour discovery service).

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, you aren't allowed direct access to the Bluetooth, but rather, you are able to use certain API calls that will search for nearby devices. However, I'm not a developer currently, so I can't point you at any documentation. Perhaps someone else can back me up with a bit more information.

Comment: i don't care how exactly i need to do this, all i care about is how to communicate with a serial port on other device with bluetooth.

Comment: Becoming a developer now (I've been meaning to do this anyway). Perhaps I can find something and point you in the correct direction.

Comment: Looks like it might take a while to get my activation e-mail. I'll get back to you as soon as I can.

Comment: that's impossible. developers can't just use some other devices via bluetooth, device should be "made for ipod and works with iphone" certified =(

Comment: The ones that hook up through the dock connector have to be, but I am not sure about the Bluetooth connection. P.S. I got my activation key, iPhone apps here I come!

Answer (score 1):

My iphone 3G & 4 will connect to my Sony BT1500 car head unit which was made well before iPhone existed (i.e it's not iPod signed).