# What part of the iPhone SDK handles bluetooth?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, gamekit

I'd like to be able to send data to a Mac with bluetooth from an iPhone? Is this possible? I think GameKit allows you to connect two iPhones, but I can't see anything about connecting to computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DUPE, [iPhone SDK 3.0: where is the Bluetooth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989163/iphone-sdk-3-0-where-is-the-bluetooth)

Basically, not easy, not really exposed, probably better to use Bonjour for this purpose:

http://www.mobileorchard.com/tutorial-networking-and-bonjour-on-iphone/