# Can a file be transferred from iPhone to Mac using Bluetooth programmatically?

Tags: iphone, macos, bluetooth

Can a file be transferred from an iPhone to another iPhone/iPod/iPad and to my Mac/PC using Bluetooth using a iPhone App?

I posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314946/can-a-file-be-transferred-from-an-iphone-to-mac-os-x-using-bluetooth-closed) yesterday with same content. This was migrated to superuser.com.

Comment: it was probably closed because the question wasn't clearly a developer question. It can be read as a user question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[iPhone SDK 3.0: where is the Bluetooth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989163/iphone-sdk-3-0-where-is-the-bluetooth)
in short: no.

Answer (score 0):

I have not ever tried it, but GameKit exists on the iPhone, and the Mac - as part of that you can establish a network connection between two systems locally over bluetooth.  You should be able to use that connection to transfer any data you like.

What you cannot do is write an iPhone application that makes use of the standard Bluetooth file transfer protocol - that is not supported.  If you are open to a custom Mac/PC client though, it will work (PC client might be a lot trickier).

Comment: GameKit really isn't suitable for file transfers—the size of the data chunks it's willing to send isn't well defined and it can get really unreliable when you've sent a ton of data in a single session.