# iPhone Bluetooth SDK - discover Android / Windows phone 7 devices and background discovery

Tags: iphone, android, bluetooth, autodiscovery

I am an Android developer and .Net developer and not yet have acquired the needed knowledge regarding iOS .
I did a search on-line but couldnt get conclusive answers to several questions I have which are the following :

1.iOS Bluetooth , do I have to use the Bonjour or Game Kit or can I access a lower level API.

2.Do currently I have an option to perform pairing between an iPhone device and an Android device ?

3.Can an application access the iPhones MAC ID and Friendly ID Bluetooth slots and change them while its in the background ? Or while the device is sleeping ?

4.Can an application set if the iPhone is discoverable or not discoverable to other devices - not iPhone ? Can it perform it while in the background ?

Regards !

Jessy85

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful to you: [How can an iPhone access another non-iPhone device over wireless or Bluetooth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065459/how-can-an-iphone-access-another-non-iphone-device-over-wireless-or-bluetooth)

Generally, there is **NO** option to communicate with non-iOS device via bluetooth in regular iOS API. GameKit is intended for using between only iOS devices. However I don't know the lower level API which open to only licensed accessory hardware developer except acquiring the license is incredibly hard differently with software license.

Comment: Differ communication and discovery , or its the same in iOS ?

Comment: In regular API, you have no access to specific bluetooth feature. The only option for bluetooth communication is GameKit but it's highly abstracted API hiding bluetooth layer completely.

Comment: @Jessy85 Here's another link for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/989163/iphone-sdk-3-0-where-is-the-bluetooth

Answer (score 0):

1) You can only get to the base API if you are developing specific hardware and are a MFi member. http://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/

2) Don't think so. But Not really sure

3) You want to change the mac id in the background? Not that I know of. Also it seems like a really questionable idea.

4) Again don't think so. Maybe with MFi but I don't know.

Comment: not even with MFi. Unless android manufacturers put apple authentication chips in their devices ^^