# iPhone app talking to circuit board via bluetooth

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, bluetooth, connection

We want our iPhone app to be able to communicate with a circuit board inside an air cleaner.

The circuit board inside the air cleaner should receive signals from the iPhone app, and based on those, do certain commands in the air cleaner.

So you should basically be able to use the iPhone app to control the air cleaner via bluetooth.

We are now searching for information regarding sending data via bluetooth to a circuit board and wonder if any of you have had any experience doing this.

### Edit

**I'm looking for a framework for this type of communication for iOS which can be uploaded to App Store, or some other resources that perhaps can help me.**

Comment: What's your specific question here? This is very vague.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluetooth functionality is available as part of the GameKit framework. Apple has some nice documentation on this available [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameKitConcepts/GameKitConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH100-SW1). Basically, you can set up communications with server/client or peer-to-peer. You could be limited by whatever bluetooth functionality is in the air filter, but if your team is designing that, then I would suggest you review apples documentation to make sure you'll be able to interact properly.

If you want to communicate with non-apple bluetooth devices, though, you need to participate in the "Made for iPod" program, as you see in these two questions:

[question 2046923](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989163/iphone-sdk-3-0-where-is-the-bluetooth)

and

[question 1065459](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065459/how-can-an-iphone-access-another-non-iphone-device-over-wireless-or-bluetooth)

Information on the "Made for iPod" program can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/)

Comment: An alternative would be to use WiFi instead of BlueTooth as it would allow you to skip the "Made for iPod" program.